# How to parse text file and retrieve only selected text?

Tags: parsing, text

In my log file I have the text in the following format:

```
18 Mar 2001 14:18:17,438 INFO DomainName1\EmpId1@Admin@3.1
18 Mar 2001 14:19:00,872 INFO DomainName2\EmpId2@User@1.3.2.0
18 Mar 2001 14:20:05,418 INFO DomainName3\EmpId3@Admin@4.3.1.0
```

I just want to get only the EmpId's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like

```
cat logfile | cut -d '@' -f 1 | cut -d '\' -f 2
```

(This assumes that you are on a Unix-like system, and also assumes that '@' and '\' won't pop up elsewhere than where you put them in your example.)